# Does Google Calendar APIs and Tools allow you to save the data on personal database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gwt, google-data-api

Here's my notion what Google Data Api is for, Google gives you their controls like Calendar,etc. I use their API to communicate to create and manage events. So does this mean i can save the events and all other data in my SQL Server database. I was thinking of creating a calendar application like "Tungle.me" has using Google Calendar but use local sql server database you know what this means right i am on .net 2.0, ASP.NET and C#. Is google doesn;t allow me to do so, can you suggest a calendar control that does same job as Google Calendar does??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong about the Google services: they are not "controls" that you can use in your app. Well, in particular case of Calendar, you can embed it in your page, but this is not the primary usage.

If you just need a calendar control for your page, that just google around - there are plenty available for asp.net.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Could you explain more of what Google Gdata/Services is, why should they expose a Api if it was used only on their products. Could you edit your answer and explain more and give me insight into this

Comment: how is it when someone can summarize in short based on their experience and you learn it for years together to know what it does. I am same situation , i read it 2wice still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress scheduler control has most (if not all) of the features that Google Calendar offers.  They have controls for ASP, Winforms, and WPF (and soon Silverlight)

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Scheduler/